# How to use Lodash to pick a key from an object with array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, lodash

I want to filter an object for my server response data.
My object Included with array of objects.

```js
const object1 = {
    _id: '12345',
    publicId: 'object-1',
    arrayOfObject2: [
        {
            _id: '12345',
            publicId: 'object-2',
            username: 'allen',
            password: '123456',
        },
    ],
};
```

For example i want to pick `publicId` from `object1` and `username` from each `object2`.

i try this but this is not working:

```js
const pickedObject = lodash.pick(object1, ['publicId', 'arrayOfObject2.username']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Lodash for this.

```js
const myObject = {
    ...object1,
    usernames: object1.arrayOfObject2.map(
        ({ username }) => username
    ),
};
```

Comment: this is true but i need object1 data too

Comment: @AliHeydari I updated my answer. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: no, because my object1 is an array too.

Comment: @AliHeydari what? No, it's not.

Comment: and i'm using `Array.map` for this

Answer (score 0):

To access the object properties, You can achieve that with the help of `dot(.)` notation. For ex : `object.key`

But If you want to access each object property value from an array of Objects. In this case you have to iterate it with the help of [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const object1 = {
    _id: '12345',
    publicId: 'object-1',
    arrayOfObject2: [
        {
            _id: '12345',
            publicId: 'object-2',
            username: 'allen',
            password: '123456',
        },
    ],
};

const res = object1.arrayOfObject2.map(({ username }) => username);

console.log(object1.publicId); // prints 'object-1' 
console.log(res); // prints ['allen']
```

**Update :** After looking into the author comment on another answer, Top level object also a part of array of objects. Hence, You can iterate that as well by using lodash `._map` method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arr = [{
  _id: '12345',
  publicId: 'object-1',
  arrayOfObject2: [
    {
      _id: '12345',
      publicId: 'object-2',
      username: 'allen',
      password: '123456',
    }
  ]
}];

const res = _.map(arr, (obj) => {
  return {
    publicId: obj.publicId,
    arrayOfObject2: _.map(obj.arrayOfObject2, (obj2) => {
     return {
        username: obj2.username
     }
    })
  }
});

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: there is no way to use Lodash ?
because i have lot of properties to pick.

Comment: @AliHeydari We can use lodash. I updated the answer. I hope it will work as per your expectation now.

Comment: yes this is what i want thanks.
but i need it in a object like this:
`const arr = [
    {
        publicId: 'object-1',
        arrayOfObject2: [
            {
                username: 'allen',
            },
        ],
    },
];`

Comment: @AliHeydari I updated my answer as per the output you want. I hope it will work as per your expectation. Please do accept this answer if it helps you. So that it will be helpful for fellow developers as well.